# Regex for add quotes around values without quotes (number and boolean)

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I receive a valid JSON file, but I would like to add " around the number values ​​and the boolean values ​​to send this JSON in a wix repeater which asks for " doubles around the number and boolean values

If someone could help me please

Exemple JSON received :

`[{"id":1238890,"category_id":1,"season_id":14866,"venue_id":null,"referee_id":null,"slug":"2022-08-12-melbourne-knights-fc-altona-magic-sc","name":"Melbourne Knights FC – Altona Magic SC","status":"inprogress","time_details":{"prefix":"","initial":0,"max":2700,"timestamp":1660296540,"extra":540}, "_id":1}]`

Exemple JSON needed:

`[{"id":"1238890","category_id":"1","season_id":"14866","venue_id":"null","referee_id":"null","slug":"2022-08-12-melbourne-knights-fc-altona-magic-sc","name":"Melbourne Knights FC – Altona Magic SC","status":"inprogress","time_details":{"prefix":"","initial":"0","max":"2700","timestamp":"1660296540","extra":"540"}, "_id":"1"}]`

I tried the code below to transform the json, without the desired result

J'ai essayé ce code là en transformant mon json en chaine string mais sans le résultat escompté..

```
const regex = /[^"\d,]?(\d+)/g;
const str = [{"id":"1238890","category_id":"1","season_id":"14866","venue_id":"null","referee_id":"null","slug":"2022-08-12-melbourne-knights-fc-altona-magic-sc","name":"Melbourne Knights FC – Altona Magic SC","status":"inprogress","time_details":{"prefix":"","initial":"0","max":"2700","timestamp":"1660296540","extra":"540"}, "_id":"1"}]

const subst = `:` + `"$1"`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Cordially

Comment: Don't put "(SOLVED)" in the subject. Instead mark the answer that provided the solution with the acceptance mark (this is not the same as voting). I rolled back that edit.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the json, re-stringify using a `replacer` function (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)). Below snippet also quotes `null`:

```js
const json = JSON.parse(`[{"id":1238890,"category_id":1,"season_id":14866,"venue_id":null,"referee_id":null,"slug":"2022-08-12-melbourne-knights-fc-altona-magic-sc","name":"Melbourne Knights FC – Altona Magic SC","status":"inprogress","time_details":{"prefix":"","initial":0,"max":2700,"timestamp":1660296540,"extra":540}, "_id":1, "someBoolean":false}]`);
 
console.log(JSON.stringify(json, 
  (key, value) => 
    /number|boolean/.test(typeof value) || value === null ? `${value}` : value, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather just convert the object than use regex

```js
const json = `[{"id":1238890,"category_id":1,"season_id":14866,"venue_id":null,"referee_id":null,"slug":"2022-08-12-melbourne-knights-fc-altona-magic-sc","name":"Melbourne Knights FC – Altona Magic SC","status":"inprogress","time_details":{"prefix":"","initial":0,"max":2700,"timestamp":1660296540,"extra":540}, "_id":1}]`

const data = JSON.parse(json)

const converted = convertToStrings(data)

console.log(converted)

function convertToStrings(obj) {
  if (['boolean', 'number'].includes(typeof obj)) {
    return obj.toString()
  }
  if (obj === null) {
    return 'null'
  }
  if (typeof obj === 'string') {
    return obj
  }
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    const newArray = []
    for (const item of obj) {
      newArray.push(convertToStrings(item))
    }
    return newArray
  }
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    const newObj = {}
    for (const key in obj) {
      newObj[key] = convertToStrings(obj[key])
    }
    return newObj
  }
  throw new Error('Unsupported property type ' + typeof obj)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much it's working !! It's been 1 week that I tried to obtain this result without success

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, converting the JSON string to an object, manipulating the object, and converting back to a JSON string is good approach.

Here is a short and sweet regex to change the JSON string directly:

```js
const jsonStr = '[{"id":1238890,"category_id":1,"season_id":14866,"venue_id":null,"referee_id":null,"slug":"2022-08-12-melbourne-knights-fc-altona-magic-sc","name":"Melbourne Knights FC – Altona Magic SC","status":"inprogress","time_details":{"prefix":"","initial":0,"max":2700,"timestamp":1660296540,"extra":540}, "_id":1, "someBoolean":false}]';
const re = /(":\s*)(\d+|true|false|null)(,\s*"|\s*[\}\]])/g;
console.log(jsonStr.replace(re, '$1"$2"$3'));
```

Explanation of regex:

- `(":\s*)` -- capture group 1: expected pattern before to be escaped values
- `(\d+|true|false|null)` -- capture group 1: to be escaped values
- `(,\s*"|\s*[\}\]])` -- capture group 1: expected pattern after to be escaped values
- `/g` -- replace more than once